# A functional equation with convolution.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

What methods do there exist to solve equations of the type:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(f(\tau)) f(t-\tau)d\tau = g(t)$$

That is: to try and find a function that convolved with itself applied twice becomes a given function $g(t)$

Comment: Based on a rather long experience in different forms of convolution, it is almost certain that there are no solution, even for very simple $g$. Could you say us why you are interested in this problem ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: Just curious. I have not found any place to apply it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some simple examples of non-uniqueness:

If $g\equiv 0$, there are *too many* solutions.  Let $f:\mathbb R\to (-\infty,0]$ satisfy $f(x)=0$ for $x\le 0$, with $f(x)\le 0$ arbitrary for $x>0$.  Then $f\circ f\equiv 0$.  (Formally, $f$ could even be non-measurable!)

If $g\equiv const.$ is nonzero, then there are still many solutions.  If $g>0$, let $f(x)=ab\chi_{[0,a]}(x)$ for some $a>0$ and $b\in(0,1)$.  Then $f\circ f\equiv ab$, and $(f\circ f)\ast f=ab\int f=a^2b$, so put $a=\sqrt{g/b}$.

Comment: I don't agree: $f○f$ is $ab\chi_{[0,a]}$, and the convolution gives a triangle function, not a constant.

Comment: Sorry, here's my answer.  I thought that $f\circ f=ab$ since $f(\mathbb R)\subset [0,a]$.  Could you explain where your claim $f\circ f=f$ comes from?

Comment: By the way, $\chi$ indicates the closed interval $[0,a]$, not the open interval $(0,a)$.  I agree that if $g=ab\chi_{(0,a)}$, then $g\circ g=g$.

Comment: Now I understand, You have found the precise reason of my misunderstanding ! Thank you very much.