# Solving for a function inside a convolution

Tags: contour-integration, functional-equations, convolution, deconvolution

I have this relationship:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{|x|}=f(x)*f(x)\ ,
\end{align}
where $*$ denotes the convolution. I want to solve for $f(x)$. My first instinct was to apply the convolution theorem:

\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}\left\{\frac{1}{|x|}\right\}=\mathcal{F}\left\{f(x)\right\}^2\implies f(x)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left\{\sqrt{\mathcal{F}\left\{\frac{1}{|x|}\right\}}\right\}\ ,
\end{align}

where $\mathcal{F}\{\}$ is the Fourier transform. According to Mathematica,
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{1}{|x|}\right)}=\sqrt{\frac{-2 \log (\left| \omega\right| )-2 \gamma }{\sqrt{2 \pi }}}\ ,
\end{align}
where $\omega$ is the Fourier conjugate variable to $x$ and $\gamma$ is Euler's constant. How should I compute the inverse Fourier transform of the above function? I was thinking of using contour integration, but I am not sure what contour I should choose.

Alternatively, is there an easier way to solve for $f(x)$, possibly using functional equation methods? I saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2320894/a-functional-equation-with-convolution), which makes me concerned that there is not a unique $f(x)$ as solution.

Comment: This is how I would do it. I'm not sure how to evaluate the inverse Fourier transform, but note that it is a distribution and you will likely have to get extremely creative.

Comment: The general idea looks good, but there are issues right at the beginning. I'm assuming you are in dimension $1$ (otherwise the FT of $|x|^{-1}$ is $c_d|\xi|^{1-d}$), and then $1/|x|$ isn't locally integrable, so doesn't define a distribution, and thus its FT isn't even defined in any obvious way.

Comment: Maybe one could get around this by looking for an $F$ with $F'=f$ and $f*F=\pm\log |x|$.

Comment: Right, I'm assuming 1 dimension, but it would be preferable if the Fourier transform would be able to work in 3 dimensions.

Comment: I'm a little uncertain by your suggestion of $\frac{dF}{dx}=f$. I want to see if I understand it. If I differentiate both sides of $f*F=\log|x|$, I get $\frac{1}{|x|}$ on the RHS, so I can I end of getting an equation that looks like $f*f+something=\frac{1}{|x|}$. I would then need to find the necessary $f$ such that $something=0$. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: @user85503: Yes, this more or less describes what I had in mind (I didn't think carefully about it), except for two details: (1) there's no constant (your "something"), you differentiated; (2) $(\log |x|)'=-1/|x|$ for $x<0$